# How to reuse WPF 3D models?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am trying to build an app in VS2013+C#+WPF for 3D traffic simulation. My problem is the performance. With just a 1500 very simple ugly cars the app becomes unusable.

I guess the reason is that I generate a new 3D model for each car:

```
Auto newAuto = new Auto();
newAuto.model = new ModelBase("car1");
```

where ModelBase is the function:

```
public ModelBase(string resourceKey)
        {
            this.Visual3DModel = Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey] as Model3DGroup; 
            this.Visual3DModel.Freeze(); //does not affect on performance for some reason 
        }
```

and car1.xaml is a car model converted from 3DS using zam3d software. After converting I tried hard to minimize the number of triangles in it. That's why the cars are ugly :)

The question is: how to load the 3D model into graphics memory once and then reuse it? Or am I doing something wrong?

please, help! I have spent soooo much time on it!!!

Comment: are the cars all visible at the same time?

Comment: The only limitation is the camera distance. Otherwise, yes, I draw them all the time.

Comment: Maybe an approach would be use simplified model when more cars are visible, and detailed ones just when you are looking closed.

Comment: That's a good idea, but i have never tried substituting the models in the scene. I think I have to try it.  And I trully beleive my scene is not so complex for such a performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF is not suitable for complex scenes, you need to switch to [OpenGL](http://sharpgl.codeplex.com/) or [DirectX](http://sharpdx.org/).

Comment: I needed this comment in order to dare switching to opengl.